# If $P$ is the only sufficient condition for $Q$ besides $Q$ itself, is $P$ necessary for $Q$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am wondering whether if $P$ is the only sufficient condition for $Q$ besides $Q$ itself (by which I mean that $[P \implies Q] \wedge [(R \implies Q) \implies (R\equiv P \vee R \equiv Q)]$, then $P$ is necessary for $Q$. I am unsure because $Q$ is sufficient for $Q$, which makes it seem that $Q$ could be sufficient for itself and it could be true without $P$ being true, meaning that $P$ isn't necessary for $Q$.

Also, is is my reasoning correct for how  I justify that for any proposition $Q$, $Q\implies Q$? I reason that because we assume that the same proposition has the same value in all contexts, the truth of $Q$ is sufficient to conclude the truth of $Q$ because $Q$ can't suddenly change into being false in the context in which we are considering its boolean value. Is this sound?

Comment: This reminds me of a similar [nonsense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742075/logic-and-iff-confusion).

Comment: $P \to Q$ does not imply $Q \to P$. period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is sufficient for $Q$, then trivially $P \land R$ is sufficient for $Q$ for each and every $R$.

So in exactly what good sense could $P$ be a sufficient condition for $Q$ and the *only* one (other than $Q$)?

Comment: Did you mean $P \vee R$ rather than $P \wedge R$? I am not seeing how the latter is always case.

Comment: No I meant what I wrote. If $P$ is sufficient for $Q$ it certainly doesn't follow that $P\lor R$ is sufficient for $Q$!  ("Kitty is a cat" is sufficient for "Kitty is warm-blooded": "Kitty is a cat or a lizard" isn't ...)

Comment: I see; is it true however that if the only conditions which imply $Q$ are conditions that imply $P$, then $P$ is certainly necessary for $Q$, right?

Comment: @Shmuel $Q$ is a condition which implies $Q$. If the only conditions which imply $Q$ are conditions that imply $P$, then in particular $Q$ implies $P$, i.e., $P$ is necessary for $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that by our *hypothesis* "$P$ is the only sufficient condition for $Q$ besides $Q$" it is meant that
$$(P\rightarrow Q)\land \big((R\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow \neg(R\leftrightarrow Q)\rightarrow (P\leftrightarrow R)\big)$$

and that by our *thesis* "$P$ is necessary for $Q$" it is meant that
$$\neg P\rightarrow\neg Q$$

The case that bothers us is when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true. Since it's the only one that makes the *thesis* false. We would like then in this case the *hypothesis* to be false as well.

Unfortunately even independent of $R$ the *hypothesis* becomes true. Which means your conjecture is not true.

Tell me if I misinterpreted. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I must confess, I am a little confused with what your interpretation of my question in symbolic logic means (I have edited my question to show how I interpret $P$ being the only sufficient condition for $Q$ besides $Q$. Also, do you have any comments for my second question in the second paragraph?

Comment: @Shmuel It is equivalent to yours! To see this remember that $\neg P\lor Q$ is equivalent to $P\rightarrow Q$ in classical logic so in your case we have that $R≡Q∨R≡P$ is equivalent to $\neg(R\equiv Q)\rightarrow R\equiv P$ which is what I wrote. For your second question I think you are overcomplicating it. If something is true, then it is true. Propositional logic doesn't account for changes in time of truth values, or I'm not sure what you're thinking of.